# Closed form of this expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, closed-form

So at my school today, we celebrated Pi Day, and we had a customary mini-olympiad. In that olympiad there was a really interesting question.

> There is a sequence: $\lbrace 1\rbrace, \lbrace 4, 9\rbrace, \lbrace 16, 25, 36 \rbrace, \lbrace 49, 64, 81, 100 \rbrace ...$ Find a closed form for $S$ where $S$ is the sum of the numbers in the nth set.

So a few observations that I made:

1. The numbers are all perfect squares (pretty obvious, I know)
2. The root of the last term of the nth set is $n$ more than the root of the last term of the previous set.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum of the first $n$ square numbers?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yup, I thought along that line but reached the complication of having to subtract the previous sums from the sum of the nth set. If that happens then I think you'll have to define the $S(n)$ in terms of $S(n-1)$ and I don't want that.

Comment: Why don't you want it? Do you want to answer the question, or don't you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson because if the terms are expressed in terms of the previous $S$ ( a recurrence relation), then that wouldn't be a closed form, right?

Comment: Let $A(n)$ be the sum of the first $n$ squares. Then $S(1)=A(1)$, $S(2)=A(3)-A(1)$, $S(3)=A(6)-A(3)$, $S(4)=A(10)-A(6)$, etc. So if you know the formula for $A(n)$, and if you can figure out where the $1,3,6,10,\dots$ is coming from, you can write down a formula for $S(n)$. Try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think that Gerry Myerson is right.  Here are some of the instruction.

First is to determine the starting number of set nth (number without square).  Let call this as $u_n$.

$u_1 = 1, u_2 = 2, u_3 = 4...$

Let assume $u_n = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1$

Noticing that set nth will have $n$ elements, then:

$u_{n+1} = (u_n + n-1) + 1 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1 + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1$

Therefore, the starting number in the nth set is $[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1]^2$.
Then:

$S_n = \sum_{k=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1}^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} k^2- \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}k^2$

And the sum of nth square number is given as:

$\sum_{k=1}^{k=n}k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Now, you can substitute and simplify to get the result.

Comment: Could you explain your method for finding that the starting number is $[\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}+ 1]^2$ and that the last number is $(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$? Sorry if this is a stupid question. I've never done sequences, and I'm only mildly familiar with them.

Comment: I updated the explanation in my answer.

Comment: No I don't mean your proof by induction, I want to know how you arrived at the hypothesis that $u_{n} = \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}+1$

Comment: Or rather it seems that you found the expression for $u_n$ after finding the expression for the last term, so instead you might explain how you found an expression for the last term in the $n^{th}$ set.

Comment: Did you find it by using some formula for geometric series? (again please excuse my lack of knowledge in sequences)

Comment: Never mind, I found the logic. Thanks loads though.